# How to use pointers in C/ returning an int array?

Tags: c, pointers, quicksort

I'm currently trying to write the code for a simple Quicksort in C, but I can't seem to understand C syntax and pointers. I'm used to coding in Java, so I'm a little confused on how to return int arrays, and what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code right now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 100
int input[MAX];

int* QuickSort(int A[], int n);
int* combine (int first[], int pivot, int last[]);

//main method to run program
int main()
{
    int i, n;

//read in input and store values in array named input
printf ("Enter several numbers separated by spaces or returnsand ended by Ctrl-D:\n");
for (n = 0; n < MAX && scanf("%d", &input[n]) != EOF; n++);

//runs QuickSort on the array
int new[n] = QuickSort(input, n);

printf("Here is your sorted array:\n");
//goes through sorted array to print values
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    printf("%d\n", new[i]);
}

int* QuickSort(int A[], int n)
{
//if array has 1 value or is empty, automatically return
if (n <= 1)
    return A;

int pivot = A[0]; 
int less[n/2];
int more[n/2]; 

int lesscount = 0;
int morecount = 0;
int i;
for (i = 1; i<n; i++)
{
    if (A[i] <= pivot)
    {
        less[lesscount] = A[i];
        lesscount++;
    }
    else if (A[i] > pivot)
    {
        more[morecount] = A[i];
        morecount++;
    }
}
int size = n/2;
return combine(QuickSort(less, size), pivot, QuickSort(more, size));

}
int* combine (int first[], int pivot, int last[])
{
int firstsize = sizeof(first)/sizeof(first[0]);
int lastsize = sizeof(last)/sizeof(last[0]);
int totalsize = firstsize + lastsize + 1;
int combined[totalsize];

int n;
for (n =0; n<firstsize; n++)
{
    combined[n]= first[n];
}
combined[n]=pivot;
n++;
int m;
for (m =0; m<totalsize; m++)
{
    combined[n] = last[m];
    n++;
}

return combined;
}
```

Comment: `input = QuickSort(input, n);`  Should not compile. input[] is not an assignable lvalue.

Comment: @wildplasser how would you fix this? Would my edit work?

Comment: The function does not need to return anything. (the function could be void) The array "is owned" by the main function, and is passed to it by a pointer (plus the number of elements). After the quicksort() function returns, the array is still at the same place (but its elements have been shuffled)

Comment: BTW: the combine() function, and the first[] and last[] subarrays don't work the way you think. Your usage of sizeof is also wrong...

Comment: @wildplasser If my current program has to combine the parts, how would this work? How would I just shuffle the elements, right now I'm just making new smaller arrays and putting them together. These are probably really simple questions, but thank you!

Comment: I hope my answer helps explain some of this.  I think of quicksort in two steps: partition and recurse.  The partition step is the shuffling and you can use a couple of additional indices into your array to track what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

### The basics

A pointer is a memory address which you can dereference and access.  It's very different from an object and is (mostly likely) just an 8-byte value.  Whereas in Java you might be able to pass around objects (which do point to some memory somewhere), in C you must be a lot more careful about what memory you're pointing.

In particular, there is a difference between the `stack` and the `heap`.  The `stack` is what your program uses to track local variables and will automatically allocate space.  On the other hand, the `heap` is usually something you need to manage yourself.  In particular, you won't get heap addresses unless you explicitly allocate it (i.e., with `malloc`).  Why the distinction?  Because the stack automatically allocates space, but also automatically deallocates space on function return.

Why does this apply to you?

Let's take a look on some of your functions:

```
int* combine (int first[], int pivot, int last[])
/* i.e., int* combine (int *first, int pivot, int *last) */
{
    int firstsize = sizeof(first)/sizeof(first[0]);
    int lastsize = sizeof(last)/sizeof(last[0]);
    int totalsize = firstsize + lastsize + 1;
    int combined[totalsize];
    /* The rest of the code */
    return combined;
}
```

You're returning `combined`, a stack allocated variable to whoever is calling your function.  While doing this is "legal" in the strict sense, it's not correct because once you've returned from the function, the program will automatically deallocate the memory.  This means you're probably getting some very confusing results and/or faults.

### Now, how do you fix this?

In your case, quicksort doesn't need more space, just some clever manipulation of variables.  Thus, you actually don't even need to use any of the sub arrays, nor do you need to return any arrays.  The neat thing about pointers is that you get an address to memory.  Thus, if you change that is pointed to (i.e., `A[0] = x`), then any other function which also knows about `A` will see that update.

### And applied to quicksort?

Your initial implementation isn't quite correct either.  Quicksort can be roughly broken down into two steps: partition and combine.  When you partition, you want to separate all values less than a pivot value from all values greater than a pivot value.  However, because you don't already know how many that is, assuming you'll have `size/2` in each partition is going to cause you trouble.

For partition, you can use an in place iterative method.  Something like this:

```
while index < end:
    if A[index] < pivot:
        index ++
    else if A[index] > pivot:
        swap(A[index], A[end])
        end --
swap(pivot, A[index])
```

(There may be some off by one errors in the above.)  The basic idea is that by keeping track of both a lower part and an upper part with two indices, you "add" the current value you're comparing against to the proper side (by moving to the next index, or swapping and decrementing the end).  And by doing this in place, you don't need to deal with memory allocation.

The recursive step then becomes knowing where your sub-pieces are and recursively calling sort of each.

Comment: I think, it would be good to mention that the declaration `int* combine(int first[], int pivot, int last[])` is precisely equivalent to the declaration `int* combine(int* first, int pivot, int* last)`. I. e. that it is really impossible to pass an array by value in C, even though the syntax suggests differently.